# Get number of lines in UITextView without contentSize.height

Tags: ios, xcode, image, swift, uitextview

I'm creating an image to export in my iOS app. I am using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext to draw the elements of the image but I've been struggling drawing a UITextView in the image.

First I create a parent view for rendering:

```
var parentView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 700))
```

Then I programatically create the textView and add all the properties. I give it x=100 and y=100 to align the text in the image. Width = 500 is good to have a margin of 100px on each side:

```
var textView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 500, 350))
textView.text = myText
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 0.70)
textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue Light Italic", size: 35)
```

Then I render the textview in context by adding it as a subview to the parent view and then I get the image for export:

```
parentView.addSubview(textView)        
parentView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())    
var newIMG = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

The problem is that the height is fixed to 350px, but sometimes the text is not long enough to use all that area. Ideally I would like to know how many lines will my text use, so I can give it a proportional height and not have a white unused area (see pic for example):

[image: Info]
Any ideas on how to render the text view with a proportional height? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a text view instead of a UILabel?

Comment: Not really, can it be done with a UILabel?

Comment: A UILabel would be excellent for this, considering it's only two lines. If you are using storyboards (which I highly suggest you do), you can alter the constraints and UILabel size to conform to the text perfectly. Just remember to set the number of lines to 2.

Comment: What you are seeing here is an imaged saved to the device's gallery. This is not the app layout, I managed to create a good layout but exporting the picture is giving me this problems!

Comment: Yep, it can (and should) be done with a UILabel. The UITextView is for handling input, and so if you're just using text that's previously been entered (or is static), the UILabel is the way to go. If you want the text centered in your label, then set the labels bounds to the top and bottom of the area. If you want it to be at the top, then use constraints and set an == constraint for the top and a >= constraint for the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to get the number of lines, but I managed to remove all that white space using textView.sizeToFit(). It worked great, hopefully someone will find this useful!

Answer (score 26):

I found the perfect solution to this problem in Apple's [Text Layout Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html). The solution Apple provides is in Objective-C, so I tested and re-wrote it for Swift.

Both methods work great and return the **exact** number of lines that are being used in a UITextView, without funky math and 100% accurate every time.

**Here is my extension to UITextView to add a `numberOfLines()` method:**

```
extension UITextView {
    func numberOfLines() -> Int {
        let layoutManager = self.layoutManager
        let numberOfGlyphs = layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs
        var lineRange: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
        var index = 0
        var numberOfLines = 0

        while index < numberOfGlyphs {
            layoutManager.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(
                index, effectiveRange: &lineRange
            )
            index = NSMaxRange(lineRange)
            numberOfLines += 1
        }
        return numberOfLines
    }
}
```

Just call this directly on your UITextView like so: `myTextView.numberOfLines()` <- returns an Int

---

**This extension is also easily converted to a method like so:**

```
func numberOfLines(textView: UITextView) -> Int {
    let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager
    let numberOfGlyphs = layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs
    var lineRange: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, 1)
    var index = 0
    var numberOfLines = 0

    while index < numberOfGlyphs {
        layoutManager.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(index, effectiveRange: &lineRange)
        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange)
        numberOfLines += 1
    }
    return numberOfLines
}
```

Just call `numberOfLines(myTextView)` to retrieve an Int of the number of lines

Comment: Doesn't give exact number of lines if last character is \n

Comment: had the same issue ^^

Comment: yes, I also had the same issue with the last character is \n